# Remote webcam stream using webkitPeerConnection00 isn't displayed

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I am trying out the sample code for peer-to-peer webcam communication in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ where both clients are implemented in the same page.

The 'local' webcam stream is displayed correctly. However, nothing shows up on the 'remote' stream and I'm not sure why.

Below is my code. I am currently testing it out on a hosted server. Thanks!

```
var localStream;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getUserMedia({'audio':true, 'video':true}, onMediaSuccess, onMediaFail);

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    localVideo.autoplay = true;
    localVideo.src = url;
    localStream = stream;
    console.log('Local stream established: ' + url);
}

function onMediaFail() {
    alert('Could not connect stream');
}

function iceCallback1(){}
function iceCallback2(){}

function gotRemoteStream(e) {
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
    var stream = e.stream;
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
    remoteVideo.src = url;
    console.log('Remote stream received: ' + url);
}   

function call(){

    pc1 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null, iceCallback1);   // create the 'sending' PeerConnection
    pc2 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null, iceCallback2);   // create the 'receiving' PeerConnection

    pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;                      // set the callback for the receiving PeerConnection to display video

    console.log("Adding local stream to pc1");
    pc1.addStream(localStream);                             // add the local stream for the sending PeerConnection

    console.log("Creating offer");
    var offer = pc1.createOffer({audio:true, video:true});  // create an offer, with the local stream

    console.log("Setting local description for pc1");
    pc1.setLocalDescription(pc1.SDP_OFFER, offer);          // set the offer for the sending and receiving PeerConnection

    console.log("Start pc1 ICE");
    pc1.startIce();

    console.log("Setting remote description for pc2");
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc2.SDP_OFFER, offer);

    // gotRemoteStream Triggers here

    console.log("Creating answer");                         // create an answer
    var answer = pc2.createAnswer(offer.toSdp(), {has_audio:true, has_video:true});

    console.log("Setting local description for pc2");   
    pc2.setLocalDescription(pc2.SDP_ANSWER, answer);        // set it on the sending and receiving PeerConnection 

    console.log("Setting remote description for pc1");
    pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc1.SDP_ANSWER, answer);

    console.log("Start pc2 ICE");
    pc2.startIce();                                         // start the connection process

    console.log("script done");
}
```

Comment: Don't use NULL value for STUN/TURN protocol/server ---- use this: var pc1 = new webkitPeerConnection00('STUN stun.l.google.com:19302', iceCallback2); --- without processing ice candidates --- you can't get remote streams!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Muaz! This is a local example I am trying out (as per the code on the tutorial page). Since 'local client' and 'remote client' are on the same page, shouldn't there be no need for the STUN server and ice candidates just yet?

Comment: (My personal opinion!) All WebRTC apps need a middle server (weather it is a SIP or libjingle) for first handshake ---- In the current RTCWeb APIs, we can use two type of protocols: STUN and TURN ---- the purpose of these protocols as I think is to generate unique ice candidates for each peer. Now it is developer's job to process/pass those candidates among peers. If you want to test locally; you must install such kind of servers (SIP/LibJingle) on your local machine. I found some mini SIP clients but they didn't work for me!

Comment: You can test my this experiment: https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/ --- it works fine on computers connected to a single modem --- but not works on different IP addresses. (You know each moden has unique IP!)

Comment: I see, I tried your app a couple of days ago but I couldn't seem to get it to work. I tried implementing a websocket server for the handshakes in another example, but I'm lost as what to do with the ice candidates. Do you send them along with the offers/answers?

Comment: Because other peer has to process ice messages generated by this peer. I'm also passing ice messages among peers. As well as offer/answer SDP too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**simpl.info RTCPeerConnection**
by Vikas Marwaha and Justin Uberti

http://www.simpl.info/rtcpeerconnection/

It's working well for me and it's very clean and simple.